# A get or set accessor required with inheritance

Tags: c#

I want to see is if the method bark will be overridden.

For some reason i am getting the error a get or set accessor required and another error when i try to call the method bark from main with  `a.bark`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace animals
{
    class Animal
    {
        public void bark {             
            Console.WriteLine("woohhoo");            
        }        
    }    

    class dog : Animal
    {        
      public void bark    
      {
         Console.WriteLine("woof");
      }    
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal a = new Animal();

            a.bark;

            dog d = new dog();

            d.bark;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method won't be overridden because it isn't marked as `virtual` (nor the override marked as `overrides`) and your example in `Main` is not making use of polymorphism (by assigning `a = new Dog()` anyway.

Comment: You need to learn C#. Find a tutorial and follow it until you understand the basic syntax of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parenthesis on your method declarations:

> Here: have a look at [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ds1QGU)

You should declare your method with () in C# and also call them using the parenthesis after the method name: `a.bark();`

```
class Animal
{

    public void bark() { 
        Console.WriteLine("woohhoo");
    }
}


class dog : Animal
{
  public void bark()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("woof");
  }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Animal a = new Animal();

    a.bark();
    dog d = new dog();
    d.bark();
}
```

Also, no, the method will no override because in C#, if you want a derived type to override a method from the base class you must mark that method with virtual in the base and override it on the derived class.

Consider refactor your code like in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/es5bjz). Note that now you can create dog in an Animal variable and method is called correctly.

```
Animal d = new dog();
d.bark();
```

Comment: i dont get the line Animal d = new dog();  is d an animal or a dog ?

Comment: For clarity, maybe make Animal an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

to override you need a virtual function.  You also need brackets for functions. If you don't have brackets it thinks it's a property

which has the basic form :-

```
public void talk
{
   get { return somevariable; }
   set { somevariable = value}
}
```

which is why it's telling you it wants a get or set

Also calling it 'bark' is weird on Animal.  So changing it a bit, what you want is something like :-

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void talk() { 
        Console.WriteLine("woohoo");
    }
}

class dog : Animal
{
  public override void talk()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("woof");
  }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();

        a.talk();

        dog d = new dog();

        d.talk();

        // this part is key, when you have a dog as an animal, when you 
        // call talk it will use the overriden method.  If you don't have
        // virtual and override, then this would go "woohoo"
        Animal da = d;
        da.talk();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to have parenthesis after bark.
C# gives you a couple options in terms of overriding.  Given the following main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Animal a = new Animal();
    a.bark();
    dog d = new dog();
    d.bark();
}
```

If you consider the following classes (Version A), this technique is called hiding.  The dog's bark method hides Animal's. Notice the new keyword in front of the dog's bark method.

```
class Animal {
    public void bark (){ 
        Console.WriteLine("woohhoo");
    }
}

class dog : Animal {
  public new void bark() {
     Console.WriteLine("woof");
  }
}

output
    woohhoo
    woof
```

Now consider the following classes (Version B) where dog's bark method overrides animal's.

```
class Animal {
    public virtual void bark (){ 
        Console.WriteLine("woohhoo");
    }
}

class dog : Animal {
    public override void bark() {
       Console.WriteLine("woof");
    }
}
```

The output is the same. So what's the difference?  Change the main method as follows and run the code with Version A and Version B.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Animal a = new Animal();
    a.bark();
    Animal d = new dog();
    d.bark();
}

Version A output
    woohhoo
    woohhoo
Version B output
    woohhoo
    woof
```